# How can i get the value of a column for the max avalaible date when the selected date in the filter is bigger than the max date avalaible

Tags: powerbi, dax

lets say i have a table1 with three products and the max date i have available data for each one

| product | max_date_aval |
| --- | --- |
| milk | 13/9/2022 |
| paper | 15/9/2022 |
| oranges | 15/9/2022 |

a table2 with the product name, the rec_date and the sales amount

| rec_date | product | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/9/2022 | milk | 13 |
| 12/9/2022 | paper | 10 |
| 12/9/2022 | oranges | 11 |
| 13/9/2022 | milk | 12 |
| 13/9/2022 | paper | 14 |
| 13/9/2022 | oranges | 16 |
| 14/9/2022 | paper | 17 |
| 14/9/2022 | oranges | 9 |
| 15/9/2022 | paper | 12 |
| 15/9/2022 | oranges | 11 |

and a typical calendar date that i use as a filet in my dashboard.

I have created a table that displays the three products and the sales like this ( when i choose "13/9/2022" in the date filter)

| product | daily_sales | MTD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| milk | 12 | 300 |
| paper | 14 | 329 |
| oranges | 16 | 321 |

what i want to achieve is that, when i choose a date in the filter that its bigger than the max available date, i want the table to display the value for the maximum date i have availiable.

For example, if i choose "14/9/2022" in the filter, i want th e table to be like this

| product | daily_sales | MTD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| milk | 13 | 300 |
| paper | 17 | 346 |
| oranges | 9 | 330 |

Currently what im getting is the one bellow ( which makes sense but i need to have all three products )

| product | daily_sales | MTD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| paper | 17 | 346 |
| oranges | 9 | 330 |

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, the dates used within the slicer need to be **unrelated** to the other two tables.

You can do this by either manually removing/deactivating the relationship between the *Table2* and *Calendar* tables and then replacing your current Sales measure with the following:

```
MyMeasure1 :=
VAR SelectedDate =
    MIN( Celandar[Date] )
VAR MaxAvailableDate =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( Table1[max_date_aval] ),
        Table1[max_date_aval] <= SelectedDate
    )
VAR DateToUse =
    IF( ISBLANK( MaxAvailableDate ), SelectedDate, MaxAvailableDate )
RETURN
    SUMX( Table2, IF( Table2[rec_date] = DateToUse, Table2[sales] ) )
```

or, if you prefer to leave that relationship active, it can be deactivated in-measure:

```
MyMeasure2 :=
VAR SelectedDate =
    MIN( Celandar[Date] )
VAR MaxAvailableDate =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( Table1[max_date_aval] ),
        Table1[max_date_aval] <= SelectedDate
    )
VAR DateToUse =
    IF( ISBLANK( MaxAvailableDate ), SelectedDate, MaxAvailableDate )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX( Table2, IF( Table2[rec_date] = DateToUse, Table2[sales] ) ),
        CROSSFILTER ( Celandar[Date], Table2[rec_date], NONE )
    )
```